# Prefix.pch not found but only when profiling

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, precompiled-headers

The app **runs** fine but when I go "Profile" I'm getting the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/J/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ajnudfmshjcjmphggazldsfhzvko/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApp-Prefix-atybgvarhtjcxtdhqwgxnbhqqgou/MyApp-Prefix.pch'
```

I think this may have something to do with installing cocoa pods, which I've since removed. How can I stop xcode from adding a second .pch ?

** EDIT **

I recently looked at the *Precompiled Headers* of another app and noticed that it was also doing the addition `.pch` but this app was profiling fine. I didn't notice an additional file of `MyApp.pch.d` which is not in my other app. I have no idea what that means but as far as I understand it shouldn't be effecting whether or not I can profile. I compared both the projects and their Prefix Header properties and they match, relatively.

Comment: Sounds like it's not named correctly in your file system. Try opening the directory in Terminal and checking to make sure the source .pch file is named correctly.

Comment: @IanMacDonald What do you mean "not named correctly"? It's adding a .pch so for that reason I know it's not named correctly. The Prefix Header in Build Settings is set to `MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch` but no matter what I put in there llvm is looking for an extra .pch. It's very aggrivating.

Comment: The file exists on your file system independent of what you enter into Build Settings. Your compiler is looking for a file named `MyApp-Prefix.pch`. The generated folder has a `MyApp-Prefix.pch.pch`. The `MyApp-Prefix.pch.pch` is copied from your project's folder tree. You need to find this file and rename it to be the file that your Build Settings indicate.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've been out of the country so thanks for be patient on my reply. I found the project file and it is named "MyApp-Prefix.pch" which looks correct to me.

Comment: Are you looking at in Finder? If you aren't showing file extensions in Finder, you won't be able to definitively know the full filename.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Excellent point but unfortunately that is the unix name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ONLY way I've been able to resolve this issue was by creating a new project and painstakingly moving each and every asset over until the app worked in the new environment. Problem solved.

Comment: I can't find the myapp-prefix.pch when I create a new project.  Do you know where it went?